# Add dynamical break tags

Tags: php

These are clients requirements:

He has, for example, in header menu this link:
'Route A From X to Y (11 Days)'..
Now, in header he wants a break line after Route A, in title he wants a break line after 'From X'.. And on the sidebar he wants it after 'to Y'.

I tried solving it like this(only solved for header right now):

```
$string = "Route A{header-break} From X to Y (11 Days)";
$header = str_replace('{header-break}','<br>',$string);
return $header;
```

Is this even good solution? Or are there any better ones?

Comment: How the content is gong to be populated? Strange requirement though.

Comment: Not really sure about he good ones but this is definitely not the bad one. But I guess the text "{header-break}" will show up on your page if not replaced. You need to think of creating your own temp html tag which will not show up or render on the page if not replaced. This will save your computing time to replace {somehing} with blank if not required in that position.

Comment: Content will be populated from mysql db

Comment: @user3002173 Just trying to understand how would you determine the requirement for breaks. If you know it before hand, why not to hard code it. why do you need a variable?

Comment: How can I know it before if it's retrieved from the database?

Comment: @Rahul Kate thanks for the tip, haven't thought of that.